# Каковы требования к EFI-образу?

Tags: gcc, ос, uefi, x86-64

Разрабатываю операционную систему с нуля по принципу "исследование посредством практики". Для загрузки используется файл для EFI. Взаимодействие с EFI урезано до минимума. В VirtualBox файл запускается через раз, в зависимости от содержимого ld-скрипта, а точнее от настроек начала образа.

На реальной машине, без любых выводов, просто возвращается в меню загрузки или выводит, что нет загружаемого носителя.

Сложно что-то привести в пример, чтобы показать проблему. Код можно получить [по ссылке](https://bitbucket.org/adokenai/nose_stage).

Гугление даёт ровно ничего в этом отношении (могу и ошибаться).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Экспериментально выявил, что образ EFI запускается, если указать адрес начала образа 0x401000.

В скрипте для `ld` указал в `SECTIONS` в самом начале `. = 0x401000;` и образ стал загружаться как на ВМ, так и на реально железе.

Страница в начале используется для служебной информации.